# Add RedHat Repo to CentOS?

Tags: centos, redhat, yum, repository

I need to install and add the RedHat repository to CentOS 7. From the instructions, I need to create a repository definition at /etc/yum/repos.d/newRepo.repo which points to my local repository as is:

```
[local]
name=newRepo
baseurl=file://path/to/YUM/repo
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
protect=1
```

and then "yum install newRepo"

The problem I am having is I cannot seem to add the RedHat repository with all the RPMs required. How can I do this?

Comment: Why would you add a RedHat repo to CentOS?

Comment: The question is: why do you think you need "the RedHat repository" (there are lots of different repositories from Red Hat). What are the dependencies you're looking for? If they're in Red Hat they're probably also in CentOS

Answer (score 2):

If your content including repodata is in the path you listed in baseurl you already added that new repo.
`yum install newRepo` is nonsense. Yum install doesn't install repositories, but packages. Try runnig `yum repolist` to get a list of repositories and a package summary for each.
There should be an entry for "local" (your newly added repository) with the amount of packages contained.

You'll have some directory containing a lot of RPM files. You also have a directory called "repodata" usually in or next to the directory that contains the RPMs.
The directory that contains the repodata subdirectory is your repository. This is where the `baseurl=` in your configuration file must point to.

In the configuration file you also define a short symbolic name for your repository and a long readable name.
The former is the thing in `[]` at the top of the file (i.e. "local" in your example), the latter is the text that follows `name=`.

So say you have the following directory structure (just an example):

```
/srv/export/software/rpm-repo
/srv/export/software/rpm-repo/RPMS <-- here are your RPMs
/srv/export/software/rpm-repo/repodata
```

Your configuration file would look something like that:

```
[myrepo]
name=My very own Repository
baseurl=file:///srv/export/software/rpm-repo
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Comment: I'm still very confused. The instructions say to point the baseurl to the RedHat one (since it has all the RPMs). However, I'm not sure what that would be? Also, the repository definition that I've listed above is verbatim to the instructions, which they say will install all required dependencies.

Comment: Andreas makes a good point, but it is a confusing issue. _Normally_ you do not add repositories via `yum install (name)`. *However*, EPEL from the fedora project (and others out there, but EPEL is the highest profile) do have a package that you can install which configures the repository. "NOTE for CentOS users
You can install EPEL by running `yum install epel-release`. The package is included in the CentOS Extras repository, enabled by default." << from https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#How_can_I_use_these_extra_packages.3F - But adding repos via a package is not the default behavior.

Comment: @ninchicken did you already understand what a repository is in the yum context?

Comment: @AndreasRogge yes I understand that we use yum to install packages, not repositories. I'm just unsure how to go about their instructions, and how to add the redhat repository as that contains many dependencies that I am seeking.

Comment: @ninchicken may I ask that dependencies you need? Almost everything available in Red Hat Enteprise Linux is also in CentOS, so you shouldn't need a Red Hat repository added.